# file_get_contents() from url that is only accessible after login (No cURL)

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I would like to access a page by file_get_contents(). But, this page is accessible only after login. I was wondering how I should write the code. No cURL please, as this page doesn't allow cURL...

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
        )
    )
);

echo file_get_contents("https://app.kajabi.com/admin/products/545108", false, $context);
```

Comment: You need to send a request to the login page and save the cookie, and then you can get the page you want.

Comment: but I have no idea how to write code for that...

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: _"as this page doesn't allow cURL"_ - you mean your own hosting doesn't allow you to use it? Or is this actually still about your problems with the login on that other site, as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/71730949/1427878 and all the previous versions of that?

Comment: yeah, it's still a problem